# why is my computer locked out with bitlocker after windows update?

Tags: windows-11

[image]I am using a hp 15T-DWxxx and recently i did a windows update. For some reason, that is after a windows update, the computer is asking for bitlocker key and I am not sure where to use it to unlock my drive. i have an important class tomorrow and i would like to ask for help if possible. I have not enabled bitlocker so its confusing as to why is it asking me for it. I have secureboot enabled and i have checked my microsoft account. there is no recovery there and I have also my organization email in it, and it also does not have any recovery key. There is recoverykeyid but im not really sure where to use it. in my microsoft account that is linked there is also no recovery key present. any help would be appreciated thank you very much.
ps. added a picture just in case someone can resolve it much faster.

Comment: The answer to your question was that it was always protected with BitLocker.  If you do not have the recovery key then you are up a creek without a paddle.  As for the reason you are being asked for a BitLocker Recovery Key, that's due to the fact, there was a configuration change that was detected.

Comment: @Ramhound well if thats the case, then how do i tell what my key is? the windows update did say bios update is in progress. is there no way to fix it?

Comment: The installation of a update through Windows Update is not considered a configuration change.  It's possible if you update you installed was the upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11, but it's not clear if that's the case, I have only the tag you used to go by.  If you don't have the Recovery Key there isn't anything you can do.  You will be unable to boot into Windows without the BitLocker Recovery Key.

Comment: Was the machine joined to Active Directory or Azure AD? Have you checked all USB sticks for a text file with the recovery key (and a matching UUID)?

Comment: @user1686 i did find a recovery.txt in my reserved drives or whatever it was. the text file was empty. the computer had already been upgraded to windows 11 and had no issues. i just did this one update and all of a sudden it gave this issue. And im sure it was using my main account instead of my work mail. work mail was linked to office 365 only. i cant find the recovery key anywhere on my computer. there is no usb with any recovery key either. and i dont think i have it linked with azure

Comment: If you're using a Microsoft Account, you may find your recovery key in there.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunately, as i stated, there is no key there.

Answer (score 0):

ehhh sooo, guess i found the key lying in my organization account for some reason. It was not being displayed their before, but in the end i found it. thanks for all the help!